# How to edit module/extensions code directly from Magento 2 admin dashboard as we can edit plugins in wordpress?

Tags: magento2, module, admin-panel

Is it possible to edit Extensions in Magento 2 admin dashboard as we can edit plugins in Wordpress?

Like in Wordpress: 
 [image]
 Is there any option in Magento 2 admin dashboard ?

Comment: This isnt possible and i would never recommend you try and edit a extension unless you know what your doing. id suggest if you are going to edit one of the extensions you put it into version control as for the editing you would need to do that via ssh or ftp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot edit any PHP files directly from admin side as of in Wordpress.

Although you can configure/change the setting for your extension from admin but **only those which are provided by your extension developer**.

Hope it finds you helpful.